# trigger message on daily basis

Tags: triggers, web

I need your suggestions in this regard.. please read patiently and share me your suggestions...
I just know the basics of PHP, Sql queries, javascript and HTML.

I've got a website developed.
in the website, i would like to send SMS to any members who have their wedding day and birthday on a daily basis.

Can we have this message being triggered on automatic manner - without anyone clicking on a button.
i am aware of batch jobs concept, but am wondering if there is a way to trigger when time changes in a php/html website.

thanks,
Samuel Mathews.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need a backend process that executes once a day and send the e-mails. depending what servers you use you can do that in different ways. for example on sql server you can use a scheduled job, on windows there are scheduled tasks, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. I hav raised a ticket wit my web server team.. :)